# Write dataframe to csv while each column is a list

Tags: r

I used for loop generated one dataframe and after the loop I tried to `write.csv` it.

However when I `str(df)` it shows this:

```
 $ 2014:List of 11
  ..$ : int 3627
  ..$ : int 6462
  ..$ : int 2063
  ..$ : int 586
  ..$ : int 388
  ..$ : num 0.77
  ..$ : num 0.52
  ..$ : num 0.485
  ..$ : num 0.125
  ..$ : num 0.103
  ..$ : int 4326
 $ 2015-08:List of 11
  ..$ : int 3697
  ..$ : int 4279
  ..$ : int 1876
  ..$ : int 358
  ..$ : int 356
  ..$ : num 0.79
  ..$ : num 0.49
  ..$ : num 0.89
  ..$ : num 0.24
  ..$ : num 0.07
  ..$ : int 30166
```

And when I try to `write.csv` it says

> Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  : 
>         unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

So how should I fix this? I think it mainly because each column are all list (although each of them all has 1 row and 11 columns).

Thanks

#### UPDATE

Here is the loop generating result part:

```
c1<-sqldf("select count(*) from output1 where a = 1")
c2<-sqldf("select count(*) from output1 where b = 1")
c3<-sqldf("select count(*) from output1 where c = 1")
c4<-sqldf("select count(*) from output1 where d = 1")
c5<-sqldf("select count(*) from output1 where e = 1")

  d1<-c1-c2
  d2<-c2-c3
  d3<-c3-c4
  d4<-c4-c5
  d5<-c1-d1-d2-d3-d4

  p1<-d1/c1
  p2<-d2/c1
  p3<-d3/c1
  p4<-d4/c1
  p5<-d5/c1

  df[,i]<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,c1), ncol=1))
  colnames(d)[i]<-paste(dates[i])
```

c1 to c5 are numbers.

and the generated df, class(df) is data.frame, but class(df[,i]) is list..as mentioned at the top of the post.

Comment: Do you have a list of list of lists?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(df, unlist))
write.csv(df2, 'yourfile.csv', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

#### data

```
df <- list(`2014`= list(3627, 6462, 2063), `2015`=list(3697, 4279, 1876))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,  I tried your way and the original df has 11 obs and 20 variables, the code made df2 as 1 obs and 220 variables...... Do you know how to fix this? Thanks again

Comment: @KarlTian I created the dataset guessing on the structure of your dataset.  Can you update your post with the dput output of `dput(head(df,5))`